# Fire event on slick next arrow click in angular, dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried attaching a click event on the dynamically generated slick-next arrow, but the events don't appear to work properly. Something like this in the controller:

```
var slickNextButton = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-next");
```

My main goal is load a new set of items into the slick menu via a rest call when the next arrow is clicked.

I am using angular-slick for this which has a slick directive built in. If there's a configuration option for this, I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: The rest of your code?

Comment: Show us how you are registering the event listeners

Comment: Don't do DOM manipulation in the controller. This belongs in a directive.

Comment: you can use var slickNextButton = $("body .slick-next");

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I'm using angular-slick which wraps slick.js with it's own directive. Perhaps there's a function I'm not using? The documentation isn't great.

Answer (score 0):

As other people mentioned you should use directives but if you REALLY want to handle click from controller you can use jquery "on" event but not on the element itself. Attach your event to document object instead. Something like this.

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".my-arrow-selector", function(e){console.log("click")});
```